# Current clamp mains appliance

Tags: current, mains

I want to measure the current to a device using a current camp.  I have a mains extension cable I plug the device in and I strip the mains extension cable to reveal the live, neutral and ground wires. I then clamp the current clamp around the live wire. All fine.

I'm thinking that maybe there are commercial extension cables with the 3 wires pre-exposed (albeit in their own insulation) so I don't have to strip myself? I've tried searching but I'm not sure what those cables would be called or if there are other solutions? My main concern is with the safety of the DIY solution because I have to provide it to others.

Comment: This is an electrical engineering site and not an extension of radio shack or Maplin.

Comment: user2633388 What is wrong about stripping a cable by yourself?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking for specific product recommendations are considered off-topic here.

Comment: I don't really want a product recommendation.  Just what it is called.  I have searched but cannot find what people with current clamps use.  I can strip myself but it makes other people (who I give the device to) nervous, so I wanted a product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mainstream multimeter and current clamp manufacturers such as Fluke, etc. sell the device you are looking for. Check DigiKey, Mouser, Grainger, etc. It is not an extension cord per se, but rather a plastic fixture which connects in-line with your appliance's AC mains plug. The conductors are divided inside this fixture and an aperture is provided to insert the arms of the clamp such that it encircles just one of the conductors. Often this fixture is supplied with the AC Clamp when you purchase it. But, it can also be purchased separately.